# Best way to send multiple versions of a JSON object through php to JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to send multiple iterations of a JSON object as I read a text file.  I want to read the file and store each iteration in an object.  My goal on the client side is to iterate through the objects.  Is my below method ideal?

```
<?php

$myFile = $_GET['filename'];

$file = fopen($myFile, "r");
$$response = "[ ";

$data = array();
$json = array();
while (!feof($file))
{
   $row = array();
   $currentLine = fgets($file);
   $parts = explode(" ", $currentLine);
   $length = sizeof($parts);
      $time = $parts[0];
      $where = $parts[$length-1];
   $json['where'] = $where;
   $json['time'] = $time;   
   $data[] = $json;
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Thats is the proper method AFAIK.

Comment: I assume your using ajax to get this data? From what I've done with PHP and Ajax it looks like a good way to do it. You may want to try posting this on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to see if you get some more hits as well.